# Does zypper support wildcards for versions?

Tags: opensuse, suse, zypper

Using zypper, is there some way to install a version using the a wildcard or something similar?

```
# zypper install A=0.13.*
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'A=0.13.*' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'A=0.13.*' found.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.
```

Or is there a way to search on the version and have it piped into a zypper install (without writing a shell script)?

```
# zypper se A=0.13
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
No packages found.
# zypper se 'A=0.13*'
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
No packages found.
```

Yum supports "**yum install A=0.13.***".  It seems that zypper should be able to too.

(SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12, zypper 1.11.14)

Answer (score 1):

Search  for YaST packages (quote the string to prevent the shell
              from expanding the wildcard):
              $ zypper se 'yast*'

you just have to use quotes =)

Comment: I'm afraid you answered a question I didn't ask. =)  I know about using the quotes for the package name, but it's using a wildcard for the version is the question I'm asking.

Comment: zypper up 'yast*' - will be used to upgrade all yast packages wihi start with yast. Good to know. I did not previously